# Is it possible to reuse flags in Go?

Tags: go, kubernetes-helm

I'm working on a project and I'm wondering if there is a way to reuse flags while running the command in Go.

Flag should be optional argument for every plugin name as seen below.

```
command plugin1 --version=1.0 plugin2 --version=1.2 plugin3 plugin4 --version=3.7
```

Is there a way to implement such behavior? If so, what's the best practice to do it?

Comment: you can define an sliceFlag but you have hard times knowing which flag were provided after which plugin. You need to manually iterate os.Args to know. Better to make it like a docker image `command plugin1:1.0`

Comment: Well you can but good luck parsing that mess. To deal with commands and their flags I use cobra and viper.

Comment: I also thought about that and I think I'll just go with ```plugin:version``` convention

Comment: @OussamaBenGhorbel, cobra wont help you a whole lot with this.

Answer (score 1):

Your basic problem is that such command driven CLIs are built hierarchically. For example, `docker container rm`, `container` is a subcommand of `docker` and `rm` is a subcommand of `container`. If you project that to your use case, you should quickly see the problem. In your case `plugin1` would be a subcommand of `command`, `plugin2` a subcommand of `plugin1`, `plugin3` a subcommand of `plugin2` and so on. However, I think you would like to make all these commands subcommands of `command` directly.

Since you didn't give any details on what you are using to build the CLI, be it the standard library or something like Cobra. So I can't give exact implementation details here, but what you could do is to choose a more appropriate and plugin specific flag instead of the generic name `version`. Then you could share the version directly to this flag.

So for example:

```
command --plugin1=1.0 --plugin2=1.2 --plugin3 --plugin4=3.7
```

The problem is, of course, that the plugin itself is no longer a command, so it's hard to specify other plugin-specific flags. Whether this works for your case, only you can know.

Answer (score 0):

You can manually parse the `os.Args` slice, something like this:

```
//plugin1 --version=1.0 plugin2 --version=1.2 plugin3 plugin4 --version=3.7
plugins := make(map[string]string)
lastPlugins := make([]string, 0)

if len(os.Args) > 0 {
    for i := 1; i < len(os.Args); i++ {
        if strings.HasPrefix(os.Args[i], "--version=") {
            if len(lastPlugins) == 0 {
                log.Fatal("No plugin provided for " + os.Args[i])
            }
            version := strings.TrimPrefix(os.Args[i], "--version=")
            for _, p := range lastPlugins {
                plugins[p] = version
            }
            lastPlugins = make([]string, 0)
        } else {
            lastPlugins = append(lastPlugins, os.Args[i])
        }
    }
}
if len(lastPlugins) > 0 {
    log.Fatal("No version provided for plugins " + strings.Join(lastPlugins, ", "))
}
fmt.Println(plugins) //map[plugin1:1.0 plugin2:1.2 plugin3:3.7 plugin4:3.7]
```